# store s3 images in testing machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

I am working with zf2, and and storing my user profile pictures in my public folder, like this

```
zf2-project/public/uploads/users/photo.png

so i will be configuring the above path like in config file:

ASSET_BASE_URL = "http://my-project/uploads/users"

and while retrieving, <img src = ASSET_BASE_URL. $photo; >
```

In my production machine, i am storing the images outside the project folder

```
my project is in opt/mybucket/uploads/users/photo.png
```

my boss said that, when we put the images in the above place, it will mount directly to amazon bucket.

so i will be accessing the file from the following url..

```
http://s3.amazonbucket.com/uploads/users/photo.png
```

ASSET_BASE_URL = "http://s3.amazonbucket.com/uploads/users/photo.png"

```
i.e <img src = ASSET_BASE_URL.$photo; >
```

for the above scenarios, its ok to do like that, local machine and production machine.

But how can i do that in testing machine, because i am not using amazon service here. My boss said that, find the way to do this.

Because the scenario here is,

storing images in /opt/virtual-bucket/users/

But my project folder is in /var/www/my-project/

How can i show the images here in img src..

/

Anyone got idea, can you help me on this,

Comment: Why don't you use a test S3 bucket for your test environment?

Comment: @RodrigoM Thanks for the suggestion, as you said i asked for the test bucket